# Dashed line in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, path, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to find some examples or some ideas how to draw a Path with dashes only on one side.

As you understand, `DashArray` is not suitable there. My proposal is to create dashes manually but it seems very difficult.

Any ideas?